# Including many external layouts in a single XML file affects performance?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I'm writing an application that uses a bunch of forms. Every form is designed in a separate XML file and then included into another "main" XML file. Then, what I do programmatically is to set the visibility of just one of them to VISIBLE, and the rest are set to GONE, and this changes according to a spinner that selects what form you want to see.

So far I've only added 4 forms and everything seems to work fine, but the app is meant to hold like 30 different forms.

Is this alright or should I inflate and replace the forms like Fragments? Every form has its own class that manages the widgets and logic, and these classes implements an interface so  I can use polymorphism to clean or send the form.

Part of my main.xml where I embeed the forms

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/fr_form_layouts"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/fr_layout_1"
        android:visibility="gone"
        layout="@layout/my_layout_1"/>
    <include
        android:id="@+id/fr_layout_2"
        android:visibility="gone"
        layout="@layout/my_layout_2"/>
    <include
        android:id="@+id/fr_layout_3"
        android:visibility="gone"
        layout="@layout/my_layout_3"/>
    <include
        android:id="@+id/fr_layout_4"
        android:visibility="gone"
        layout="@layout/my_layout_4"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is an example of a class I use to manage a form

```
public class MR01FormWidgets implements MyFormInterface {
    private EditText someEditText;
    private View view;

    public MR01FormWidgets(View view) {
        this.view = view;
        //Initialize widgets with findViewById
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isFormValid()  {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void cleanForm() {
        //Cleans form
    }

    @Override
    public void sendForm() {
        //Sends form
    }

}
```

Then, on my Main Activity I have something like:

```
//The spinner defines the layoutId and calls this method
private void replaceFormView(View view, int layoutId) { 
    view.findViewById(visibleForm).setVisibility(View.GONE);//Hides the previous form
    visibleForm = layoutId;//sets the new visible form
    view.findViewById(visibleForm).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//makes it visible

    MyFormInterface currentForm;

    if(visibleForm == R.id.fr_layout_1)
        currentForm = new MR01FormWidgets(view);
    else if(visibleForm == R.id.fr_layout_2)
        currentForm = new MR02FormWidgets(view);
    //And so on...

}
```

So basically what happens here is that I have all my forms embeeded and hidden in a single layout, so I can manage all its widgets with a single View object. But again, is this OK?

Comment: You could use ViewStubs - https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/loading-ondemand.html.  Too many active layouts could cause issues on slower devices, you'd have to profile though to see if it was an issue

Comment: Some things may slow down when you have hundreds or thousands of widgets in a layout, even if many of them are `GONE`. And, having hundreds or thousands of widgets will take literally megabytes of heap space, which you may run out of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a view's visibility is set to gone it does not get rendered. This means that having hundreds of hidden views in a layout does not slow down performance when changes happen in the views that are visible.

Loading hundreds of views from an xml then you ll see a performance issue when your activity starts, because parsing such a big xml file is too much work.

If you load those views programmaticaly you wont have such a big performance issue at your activity's start...However all those views hold objects and that leads an increase of your app's memory usage. Depending on what other things you do this could lead to a serious memory problem.

You should choose one of the solutions provided by the Android SDK for handling cases like this. ViewPager, ViewStub, Fragments etc...These approaches will save you from memory problems as they destroy the unnecessary views when they should be destroyed (assuming that you will implement them correctly)

Comment: I already checked ViewStub and that seems like a more clean better-performance solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should use a `FrameLayout` as a parent, and not `RelativeLayout` when you're worried about performance.

If a view is `GONE` it will be skipped most of the time, as you can see e.g. here in this [`FrameLayout.onMeasure`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/5.0.0_r2-robolectric-0/android/widget/FrameLayout.java#429) implementation. So the fact that you have one view visible and 29 views hidden should not be *too* bad for the performance.

### But 30 is a lot

Even though the performance impact might not be too bad once it's running, **all those views need to be inflated.** There will be a delay, probably even some freeze.

I'd start worrying about my implementation after adding the 4th view, get somewhat worried around the 7th and when I hit 30 I'd be sure that I had missed something.

If you have a list of objects you should use some sort of adapter and probably manage those views in a more dynamic fashion. Take a `ViewPager` for example: It will only inflate the `View` that's visible, and the neighboring views on each side. But this all depends on how it should behave.